# How can I upload QPixmap image by http post?

Tags: image, qt, http, upload

I want to upload `QPixmap` image by HTTP post but I don't want make file in my directory.

I've already succeeded to upload file by HTTP post but I need to upload `QPixmap` (not a file).

Anyone know how can I upload `QPixmap` to HTTP post?

```
QFile* temp = new QFile("test.png");
```

uploading by file was succeeded.

I need to upload `QPixmap`:

```
QByteArray bytes;
QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer(&bytes);

buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
(QPixmap)file->save(buffer,"PNG");
/////////////////////////////////////
identification MultiPart and HttpPart
/////////////////////////////////////
buffer->setParent(multiPart);
multiPart->append(imagePart);

m_reply = m_nam.post(request,multiPart);
```

Uploading was done. but Image was None.

I don't want make File in my Directory.
I want upload Image to HTTP Server Directly

Comment: You can *post* `QByteArray` as well, and most Qt containers handle the [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#QDataStream-2) which can be set on a `QByteArray*` instead of a file.

Comment: QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(const char*)image->bits(),image->byteCount());
QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer(&bytes);

buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
 and i uploaded buffer, there was something uploaded by png file. but i coudln`t check my image from Server, when i load picture what i uploaded, it was empty image

Comment: well. i got it. do you mean upload without QHttpMultiPart class? i found some example https://forum.qt.io/topic/11086/solved-qnetworkaccessmanager-uploading-files